# file formats that can be read using PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

What kind of file formats can be read using PIG?

How can I store them in different formats? Say we have CSV file and I want to store it as MXL file how this can be done? Whenever we use STORE command it makes directory and it stores file as part-m-00000 how can I change name of the file and overwrite directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what kind of file formats can be read using PIG? how can i store them in different formats?

There are a few [built-in loading and storing methods](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/func.html#load-store-functions), but they are limited:

- BinStorage - "binary" storage
- PigStorage - loads and stores data that is delimited by something (such as tab or comma)
- TextLoader - loads data line by line (i.e., delimited by the newline character)

[piggybank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PiggyBank) is a library of community contributed user-defined functions and it has [a number of loading and storing methods](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pig/trunk/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/), which includes an XML loader, but not a XML storer.

---

> say we have CSV file n i want to store it as MXL file how this can be done?

I assume you mean XML here... Storing in XML is something that is a bit rough in Hadoop because it splits files on a reducer basis, so how do you know where to put the root tag? this likely should be some sort of post-processing to produce wellformed XML.

One thing you can do is to [write a UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/udf.html#eval-functions) that converts your columns into an XML string:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE customudfs.DataToXML(col1, col2, col3);
```

For example, say `col1`, `col2`, `col3` are `"foo"`, `37`, `"lemons"`, respectively. Your UDF can output the string `"<item><name>Foo</name><num>37</num><fruit>lemons</fruit></item>"`.

---

> whenever we use STORE command it makes directory and it stores file as part-m-00000 how can i change name of the file and overwrite directory?

You can't change the name of the output file to be something other than `part-m-00000`. That's just how Hadoop works. If you want to change the name of it, you should do something to it after the fact with something like `hadoop fs -mv output/part-m-00000 newoutput/myoutputfile`. This could be done with a bash script that runs the pig script then executes this command.